# Manipulating a file with sed

Tags: sed

I have a file called `students.txt` and it contains the following data in the format `Surname, Forename: day.month.year: Degree`:

```
Smith, John: 15.01.1986: MSc IT 
Taylor, Susan: 04.05.1987: MSc IT 
Thomas, Steve: 19.04.1986: MSc MIT 
Sennick, Joseph: 01.12.1987: MSc IT
```

I'm trying to return all lines in the format `Forename,Surname: day.month.year`, but without the `MSc` degree being studied. So far I have:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\),(.*\)/\2/\1/' students.txt
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Hint: how many fields are there?  You are only creating two groups/backreferences, and I think you want three.

Comment: Yes, this is homework. We've seen this question at least twice before this month.

Comment: Do you need `Forename,Surname` or `Forename, Surname`? Is this space missing on purpose or by mistake?

Comment: (Forename,Surname), there is no any space between the comma and surname. what I have written is correct.

Comment: Should we merge with http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10489/switch-from-grep-to-sed?

Answer (score 2):

Although, the following solution is non-generic, if the data format remains same then the following solution will work as well;

```
sed -r 's/^([A-Za-z]+), ([A-Za-z]+): (([0-9]{2}\.){2}[0-9]{4}): .*$/\2,\1: \3/' students.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
sed -e 's/\([^,:]*\), *\([^:]*\)/\2, \1/;s/:[^:]*$//' student.txt
```

The first statement (separated by `;`) searches for the Surname, delimited by comma-space, and Forename, delimited by colon, and swaps them, using a comma-space separator.  The second statement searches for the last colon and removes that and anything to the end of the line.  As someone mentioned this could be handled by awk.

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=":"}{split($1,N,", ");$1=N[2]", "N[1];NF=2;print}' student.txt
```

Q.E.D

Answer (score 1):

For `sed` you'll want three back references. The first delimited by the comma and the second two delimited by the colon

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*\), \([^:]*\): \([^:]*\).*$/\2, \1: \3/' students.txt
```

However, when dealing with delimiter and fields, `awk` is really the tool to use because you can specify a field separator which can be a regex.  In this case our field separator is either a comma or colon folowed by a space.

```
 awk -F'[,:] ' '{printf("%s, %s: %s\n",$2,$1,$3)}' students.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues with your command,

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\),(.*\)/\2/\1/'
```

is

1. The parentheses are not balanced as you have forgotten a backslash in front of the second opening parenthesis.
2. The replacement text contains an un-escaped `/`.
3. Even with the above fixed, it will not do what I guess you would like it to do.

The syntax-corrected command:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\),\(.*\)/\2\/\1/'
```

With the given data, this will produce

```
 John: 15.01.1986: MSc IT /Smith
 Susan: 04.05.1987: MSc IT /Taylor
 Steve: 19.04.1986: MSc MIT /Thomas
 Joseph: 01.12.1987: MSc IT /Sennick
```

i.e., it will pick up the first name and the rest of the line after the comma and swap these around with a `/` in-between.

What I believe you attempted is

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\), \([^:]*\):/\2,\1:/'
```

which produces

```
John,Smith: 15.01.1986: MSc IT
Susan,Taylor: 04.05.1987: MSc IT
Steve,Thomas: 19.04.1986: MSc MIT
Joseph,Sennick: 01.12.1987: MSc IT
```

This is the expected output, except that it still contains the degree at the end.  To delete the degree, we can do a second substitution:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\), \([^:]*\):/\2,\1:/' -e 's/:[^:*]*//'
```

This gives you

```
John,Smith: MSc IT
Susan,Taylor: MSc IT
Steve,Thomas: MSc MIT
Joseph,Sennick: MSc IT
```

---

There are several other ways to do this.  With `awk`, for example:

```
$ awk -F: -v OFS=: '{ d=$2; split($1,a,", "); $0=""; $1=a[2] "," a[1]; $2=d; print }' file
John,Smith: 15.01.1986
Susan,Taylor: 04.05.1987
Steve,Thomas: 19.04.1986
Joseph,Sennick: 01.12.1987
```

Here, we rewrite each line from scratch using bits parsed from the original line.  The name is constructed from the bits we get from explicitly splitting the name field on comma-followed-by-space.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than sed, it might be easier use awk with a field separator of ':', and just print the first two fields.

Comment: OP also wants the first field modified.

Comment: He asks for `sed` because it's homework and they are forced to do it in `sed` :)

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have to use `sed`, use the `cut` command.

`cut -d : -N 1-2 students.txt`

would do the trick

Comment: The first field also needs to be swapped around the comma.