# Switch from grep to sed

Tags: text-processing, grep, sed

I have a files `students.txt`, with lines of the form:

```
Surname, Forename: Day.Month.Year: Degree
```

For example:

```
Smith, John: 15.01.1986: MSc IT
Taylor, Susan: 04.05.1987: MSc IT
Thomas, Steve: 19.04.1986: MSc MIT
Sellen, Jo: 03.07.1987: MSc CSE
```

How can I change the command below into a `sed` command to return all the surnames of students who were born in 1987?

```
$ grep 1987 students.txt | grep -o "^\(.*\),"
```

Comment: You do realize this is cheating ;) There's a reason for homework assignments.

Comment: Should we merge with http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10200/manipulating-a-file-with-sed

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -n '/1987/s/^\([^,]*\),.*$/\1/p' students.txt
```

or as Glenn pointed out:

```
sed -n '/1987/s/,.*//p' students.txt
```

Comment: A bit simpler: `s/,.*//`

Comment: thanks @glenn. You know I was looking my answer yesterday thinking there must be a faster way and then I thought about `/1987/,.*/d` then I realized ,no, that deletes the entire line.  For some reason your answer escaped me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go with awk I would suggest a different answer to Johnsyweb's. The power of awk includes choosing the field separator(s):

```
awk -F'[,: ]*' '$3 ~ /1987$/ {print $1}' students.txt
```

But the question was about sed, so I believe SiegeX should get the better vote.

Comment: > It's nice that you point out that this question is notionally about `sed`, and probably *user5836* must use `sed`, but one of the good things in this forum is the amount of tangential information that comes from 'related' issues... eg. mentioning the multiple field seperator (-F) is great for me, as I was wondering how to do that with awk... so you get a +1 from me :)  with no demerrit implied to the sed answer.... Seeing all the alternatives is good :)

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem is well-suited to `awk`:

```
% awk '/\.1987:/ {gsub(/,.*/, ""); print}' students.txt 
Taylor
Sellen
```

Or, specifying a column, rather than the whole line (making it easier for you to customise, should you wish to add other columns in :

```
% awk '/\.1987:/ {
        gsub(/,$/, "", $1);          
        print $1;
}' students.txt
Taylor
Sellen
```

Comment: I like the fact you made the date *more specific* than just *1987*; to reduce the likelyhood of clashing with 1987 appearing eslewhere in the line.... I've just started using awk, and noticed that in this case, the following will work too (in your first example).... `{sub(/,.*/,"")`

Comment: @fred.bear: Thank you. And thanks for pointing out that I didn't need `gsub`. The check for *1987* could be localised to the end of column 2, thus: `awk -F':' '$2 ~ /\.1987$/ {sub(/,.*/, ""); print}' students.txt`